# read passport information (NFC Reader)

Tags: nfc, reader

when try to access this InputStream dg11In = service.getInputStream(PassportService.EF_DG11) DG11File dg11File = new DG11File(dg11In);  I get error  net.sf.scuba.smartcards.CardServiceException: File not found, CAPDU = 00A4020C02011D, RAPDU = 6A82 (SW = 0x6A82: FILE NOT FOUND)

Please if someone knows a solution to the problem can they help me

Comment: There might be 2 reasons for this error: a) (the most obvious) the file is realy not existens as it is not mandatory. b) the data in this file is "more confidential" than basic data and is revealed only after running an authentication by an "official" key or certificate that is issued to (e.g.) Border Patrol only.